# What's with asking everyone if they've voted?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

I'm seeing a huge burst of people asking in comments whether answer writers have voted, and I don't get it? Often they aren't even the question asker! People will vote or they won't and that's their business. What's going on?

Comment: I agree. Answering a question is completely unrelated to whether or not the question merited an upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed this a couple weeks ago and flagged one or two of the comments as being excessive noise.  If you notice someone posting a bunch of the same "why didn't you vote" comments, you can flag one of comments for moderator attention.

The thing is, voting is good (which is why I do it so much), but comments about it are a distraction.  If someone's going to vote, they'll probably do it when they first see the question, so any sort of comment about voting just gets in the way of everyone else.

Comment: please do flag these, they are noise and should be deleted. If we notice a pattern of specific users doing it we may choose to intervene further.

Comment: The person asking the question in the comments explained his reason: the upvotes encourage the new poster to come back.